# strtotime returning wrong time

Tags: php, strtotime

`echo date('Y-m-d h:m:s',strtotime('2008-11-03 16:00:29'))`

Returns  2008-11-03 04:11:29

I've tried changing my default time zone and adding GMT,UTC,PTC behind the string and nothing will change the output. How do I get strtotime to match the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'Y-m-d H:i:s'` if you want 24-hour time, or add the am/pm to the end with `'Y-m-d h:i:s a'`

Answer (score 1):

You need `i` for minutes and `H` for 24-hour.

See [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation.

`m` is month, which is why your time has 11 as minutes, the same as the month.